# Putting a selector inside a :hover?

Tags: css

Is it possible to modify another element that sits outside a hover selector?

For example:

```
#first-element img:hover {

}
#second-element {    
  background:url('#');
}
```

So that you can modify a second element outside a first element upon hovering the first element?

Thanks.

Comment: Not if we're just talking pure CSS - there is [no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was an img:hover. img does not support child tags, so for your example, no, as null said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to change style properties of other elements with onmouseover and onmouseout atributes:

HTML:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="Image to hover" onmouseover="overFunction();" onmouseout="outFunction();"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function overFunction () {
    document.getElementById("second-element").style.backgroundImage="url('1.jpg')";
}
function outFunction () {
    document.getElementById("second-element").style.backgroundImage="url('2.jpg')";
}
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/H4ubB/

Comment: I've modified your Fiddle to work with the sole use of html and css. Thought you might be interested in it jsfiddle.net/YuJMm/

Comment: Yes. But the css only works with sibling elements. The JS solution is the only way for adding hover effect to the image nested in the first div

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not possible.

If you change the approach to the problem and the elements directly follow after each other you could do something like:

`#first-element:hover + #second-element{}` which applies the style to the second element if the first-element is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

If the element to be affected is a sibling of the hovered element, then its possible:

```
<a href="">Sometext</a>
<p class="p">Another text</p>
<p class="sp">Another text again</p>

a:hover ~ .sp {
  color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/Cypue)

Comment: Mind giving a vote?...

Comment: don't have high enough reputation. thanks though!